# Template does not exists for cookbook elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to write my first wrapper chef cookbook around elastic search and have run into a problem when running elasticsearch_configure and elasticsearch_service

The error goes like this

```
RuntimeError
  ------------
  File templates/default/elasticsearch.in.sh.erb does not exist for cookbook elasticsearch
```

I can confirm that the elasticsearch cookbook does have the file in question.

The offending resources

```
elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch-logging'

elasticsearch_service 'elasticsearch-logging' do
   service_actions :enable
end
```

I am testing all of this with chef-solo using `chef-solo -c config.rb -j test.json`

config.rb

```
cookbook_path ["/tmp/cookbooks",
               "/user/.berkshelf/cookbooks/"]
local_mode true
chef_zero.enabled true
```

test.json

```
{
   "run_list": [
      "recipe[elastic-cookbook::default]"
   ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error says cookbook `elastic search` - I would expect `elasticsearch`. Check if you added the space in your wrapper cookbook.

Comment: This was just a typo it is in fact 'elasticsearch'

Comment: Can you provide the complete code of your cookbook, e.g. on Github?

Comment: @StephenKing It's the standard cookbook from https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch, just based on the error message.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot reproduce this issue. The recipe [here](https://gist.github.com/StephenKing/b698c6f873e423a01e50) works for me.

Comment: @StephenKing I used you recipe above and this failed for me also. Updated post below with how I am trying to run this on RHEL. Very new to chef!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you downloaded the elasticsearch cookbook in a directory not named elasticsearch but that sounds very strange, may you create a gist of the chef-run on debug mode (add `-l debug` to your command line)

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the cookbook to a folder `elastic-cookbook` (I think). It needs to be in `cookbooks/elasticsearch` to work.